# Can I use Facebook open graph's "article" type for forum posts?

Tags: open-graph-protocol

I'm currently integrating open graph for my forum. I discovered that they had an [article](http://ogp.me/#type_article) type and was wondering if it could be applied to my case. Only reason I ask because this sort of categorization is [recommended](https://schema.org/DiscussionForumPosting) when writing schema markup.

Answer (score 1):

These are two different things. Open graph is for constructing a tile to show instead of a plain URL when sharing it over social media and chatting apps.

The schema you provided is for [structuring your data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article) and enabling special search features for your pages on Google search.

To answer your question, yes, you can use the article open graph tag for forum posts.